# How to create a file name with the current date & time in Python?

Tags: python

Here is a functional code (create file with success)

```
sys.stdout = open('filename1.xml', 'w')
```

Now I'm trying to name the file with the current date/time (I'm not an expert in Python)

```
filename1 = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
sys.stdout = open(filename1 + '.xml', 'w')
```

I want to write out a file name with the exact date and time, it is a xml file, that the program has already create, I just need to name the file. The above code is not working.

The error returned:

```
  File "./fix.py", line 226, in <module>
    filenames = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

Answer (score 606, accepted):

While not using `datetime`, this solves your problem (answers your question) of getting a string with the current time and date format you specify:

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
print timestr
```

yields:

```
20120515-155045
```

so your filename could append or use this string.

Comment: Gotcha! time was not defined in my script and I was trying to use timedate (not work, I do not why), but with time it is clear now, the filename is created with success. Thank You so much!

Comment: I don't know why you accepted this answer when there are two answers that explain perfectly well what was wrong with the code in the question. Nothing against the way Levon did this, it works fine, but when you say "not work, I don't know why", it seems odd because you have answers that explain why.

Comment: When I tried the code above, I received a, "E               AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'" error.

Comment: @rwbyrd That is odd, I just tried those exact 3 lines (copy-paste) with Python 3.4.1 and 2.7.6 and it works - though with Python 3 you need to use `print(timestr)`. Did you copy this text from above? Perhaps a typo otherwise?

Comment: @rwbyrd You probably have an int variable called "time" somewhere in scope that is shadowing the `time` module.

Comment: For the ones looking for the strftime parameters: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 82):

Change this line

```
filename1 = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

To

```
filename1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

Note the extra `datetime`. Alternatively, change your 
`import datetime` to `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @B4NZ41 That's not true. The error message makes it clear that your code has `import datetime` somewhere.

Comment: ;) Sorry! NOW I'm using import time, before I was using import datetime

Comment: @B4NZ41 It doesn't matter what you are doing now. It matters what is in the question.

Answer (score 76):

This one is much more human readable.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
```

```
'2020_08_12-03_29_22_AM'
```

Comment: Yes but sorting by name will not sort chronologically

Comment: I guess that just requires YYMMDD instead of DDMMYY?

Comment: Now its fine for chronological sorting (it has been edited).

Comment: that is **NOT** chronologically sorted... 4 PM shows before 5 AM... I rather use: `datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%p%I_%M_%S")`

Comment: Another option for sorting the hours chronologically is using 24-hour based timestamps instead of 12-hour based timestamps using `%H` instead of `%I`, with no need to include the AM/PM indicator `%p`.

Answer (score 40):

[`now`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) is a class method in the class `datetime` in the module `datetime`. So you need

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Or you can use a different import

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Done this way allows you to use `datetime.now` as per the code in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here's some that I needed to include the date-time stamp in the folder name for dumping files from a web scraper.

```
# import time and OS modules to use to build file folder name
import datetime
import time
import os

# Build string for directory to hold files
# Output Configuration
#   drive_letter = Output device location (hard drive) 
#   folder_name = directory (folder) to receive and store PDF files

drive_letter = r'D:\\' 
folder_name = r'downloaded-files'
folder_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S_%p")
folder_to_save_files = drive_letter + folder_name + folder_time 

# IF no such folder exists, create one automatically
if not os.path.exists(folder_to_save_files):
    os.mkdir(folder_to_save_files)
```

Comment: A safer way to create your path, might be: `folder_to_save_files = shutil.os.path.join(drive_letter, folder_name +folder_time)` (also an `import shutil` statement can replace the `import os` statement )

Comment: Thanks to yosemite_k for adding the import datetime.  Yes, oneindelijk that is a safer way.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised there is not some single formatter that returns a default (and safe) 'for appending in filename' - format of the time, 
We could simply write `FD.write('mybackup'+time.strftime('%(formatter here)') + 'ext'`

```
"%x" instead of "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"
```

Answer (score 4):

This prints in an easy to read format -

```
import datetime

time_now  = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S') 

print(time_now)
```

Output: `02_03_2021_22_44_50`

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

def print_time():
    parser = datetime.datetime.now() 
    return parser.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

print(print_time())

# Output>
# 03-02-2021 22:39:28
```

Comment: Please add ``` around your code. Like this: ``` code ``` -> `code`. Also add some explaination.

Comment: You cannot create a filename containing `:` on Windows.