# Add date and time to a python created file

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I have a script that will take a screenshot. I need this script to save the file with the date and time on it. for example, I want it to look like "SC112019" or something like that.
Here is my current code:

```
import pyautogui
pic= pyautogui.screenshot()
pic.save(r'S:\Public\pjs\screenshots\screenshot.png')
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a file name with the current date & time in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607688/how-to-create-a-file-name-with-the-current-date-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use `datetime` module.

```py
import pyautogui
pic= pyautogui.screenshot()

import datetime
name = 'SS' + datetime.date.today().strftime("%m%Y") + '.png'
pic.save(r'S:\Public\pjs\screenshots\' + name)
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work. Nothing gets saved. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have verified that the path does in fact exist. I still can't get it to save there though.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed a space between screenshots\ and '.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pyautogui
pic= pyautogui.screenshot()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
pic.save(r'S:\Public\pjs\screenshots\SC{}{}.png'.format(now.month, now.year))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
from datetime import datetime
pyautogui.screenshot("D:\\Stackoverflow\\Screen"+str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S'))+".png")
```

The above code will help you!!!!!!

If you add GUI it will be better.