# How to save to a new Excel file every time i run jupyter notebook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, xlsxwriter

I run daily reports using python and xlsxwriter. The way i currently have it set up the file is overwritten every time i run it, is there a way for jupyter to save to a new file under the same Folder, for example when i run my report it will save under " outbound preformance 2/23/2022" and then the next day i run it the report would be saved under " outbound preformance 2/24/2022" and so on and so forth, bare in mind i am new to this. Here is my code:

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'A:\PATH\Outbound_Preformance\.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
OB_Preformance.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)


# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: You can append date string to file name while saving. Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607688/how-to-create-a-file-name-with-the-current-date-time-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to get today date and append it to the file name.

```
#get date
from datetime import date
today = date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

# Creating Path
folder = "'A:\PATH\Outbound_Preformance\'"
extension = '.xlsx'
path = folder+today+extension

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('r'+path , engine='xlsxwriter')


# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
OB_Preformance.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)


# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

but I would recommend you to change the date format to YYYY-MM-dd this way you will naturally order your files by date

Comment: true, let me correct it

Comment: I tried this code and i received the following error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:       it also at one point said that r was undefined. so i added r infront of the pathway

Comment: yeah that was a mistake of mine. r indicates how the path is going to be open and it should be a charactere. After your correction, did it work?

Comment: It did not work after my correction, how should the path be opened?