# When reading excel file, is there a way to program it to always read in the file that contains specific text like today's date?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, date

When reading an excel file in python to a dataframe, do I always need to enter the full file name in the string or is there a way to read a file from a folder that contains certain text, like a date? I'm being sent files with names that include timestamps with hours, minutes, and seconds in the names which requires someone to manually edit the file name.

```
df = pd.read_excel('FileName 2-23-2023 11-06-30 AM.xlsx')
```

Comment: You could always get all file names in a folder by `os.listdir(path)` and retrieve the file names that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file name with the current date & time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607688/how-to-create-a-file-name-with-the-current-date-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can read all files in a directory using os.listdir().

```
import os
import pandas as pd
for filename in os.listdir(your_folder_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    # do_something(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


to_find = "2-23-2023"
file = Path("/path/to/file/").glob(f"*{to_find}*.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(next(file))
```