# Open .txt files based on current date (python)

Tags: python, sql-server

I am building a Python script that reads the last line of a `.txt` file, and sends it to an `SQL` server database for posterior data management. I have a CNC machine that stores in-real-time data from the production processes in a `.txt` file. The default name of the `.txt` files is "industry_YYYY-MM-DD". Every day, a new `.txt` file is created with its date. I would like to run my script every morning, and have it run in the background, sending data to the `sql` database every 5 seconds. In addition, I want the script to open only the `.txt` file with the correspondent date and retrieve data from it.

At the moment the script is looking like this:

```
import time

import pyodbc

# Replace these values with your actual database connection details
server = r'****'
database = '****'
username = '****'
password = '****'
table_name = 'python2'  # Replace with your actual table name

connection_string = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'

file_path = r'C:\Users\LEOPARD\Desktop\EU\Unidades Curriculares\5ª matrícula\DPE\Punc TECHNOLOGY\Relatórios Diários\06-01-2023.txt'
previous_line = ""

while True:
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

            if lines:
                last_line = lines[-1].strip()

                # Check if the last line is different from the previous line
                if last_line != previous_line:
                    # Update the previous line
                    previous_line = last_line

                    # Check if the last line contains the substring "--"
                    if "--" in last_line:
                        print(f"New last line of the file: {last_line}")
 
                        # Connect to the SQL Server database
                        connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
                        cursor = connection.cursor()

                        # Insert the last line into the specified table
                        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (linha) VALUES (?)"
                        values = (last_line,)
                        cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
                        connection.commit()

                        # Close the database connection
                        connection.close()
                    else:
                        print("Waiting for the next line")
                else:
                    print("Same line")
            else:
                print("The file is empty.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File not found: {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    # Wait for 5 seconds before the next iteration
    time.sleep(5)
   #Ctrl + C to interrupt script
```

The script is working if I change the directory manually to the `.txt` I want to open, but i would like it to automatically open `.txt` corresponding to the date.

This is an example of the daily reports:

[image: he is an example of the daily reports]

Comment: Is your question then how do you interpolate the current date into a filename string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file name with the current date & time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607688/how-to-create-a-file-name-with-the-current-date-time-in-python). Just change the format string to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Python does have the standard [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) which you can use to get *todays* date, just transform it to a string and add it to your path or file name.

```py
import datetime
import zoneinfo
from pathlib import Path

my_file_path = Path(
    "C:/Users/LEOPARD/Desktop/EU/Unidades Curriculares/5ª matrícula/DPE/Punc TECHNOLOGY/Relatórios Diários"
)

todays_dt = datetime.datetime.now(tz=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("America/Santiago"))
todays_str = todays_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  # '2024-01-07'
print(my_file_path.joinpath(f"industry_{todays_str}.txt")) # 'C:/Users/LEOPARD/Desktop/EU/Unidades Curriculares/5ª matrícula/DPE/Punc TECHNOLOGY/Relatórios Diários/industry_2024-01-07.txt'
```